# Why are anonymous Types in EF4 different from LINQ to SQL ones?

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-4

I have the following query in LINQ to SQL to fetch all records from a Table that are not already in a jointable.

```
// <param name="id">The ID of the Person</param>
IEnumberable<object> GetUnassignedClients(int id)
{
    _db.Clients
    .Select(i => new
    {
        Client_id = i.Id,
        Person_id = id,
        Cid = id + "." + i.Id // Please don't ask why I do this. I just have to do it
        // ... some more fields
    })
    .Where(o =>
        !_db.Clients_Persons
            .Where(t => t.Person_id == id)
            .Select(t => t.Client_id)
            .Contains(o.Client_id))
    .Distinct().ToList();
}
```

Now I have started a migration to EF4 but the "Cid" part of the anonymous type with the combination `ToList()` (ToList() triggered the exception is a simplified testcase without the WHERE condition) fails with the exception:

> Unable to create a constant value of
>   type 'System.Object'. Only primitive
>   types ('such as Int32, String, and
>   Guid') are supported in this context.

Why is that so or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EF does not know how to translate the expression `id + "." + i.Id` into valid SQL which is why it fails.  You have to tell EF that it needs to convert `id` from an integer to a string.  You can do this using the [`SqlFunctions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions.aspx) class in the following way:

```
var ret = _db.Clients
.Select(i => new
{
    Client_id = i.Id,
    Person_id = id,
    Cid = SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double) id) + "." + SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double) i.Id) // Please don't ask why I do this. I just have to do it
    // ... some more fields
})
.Where(o =>
    !_db.Clients_Persons
        .Where(t => t.Person_id == id)
        .Select(t => t.Client_id)
        .Contains(id)
)
.Distinct()
.ToList()
;
```